# Web based file search in the lan?

Tags: local-area-network, search, search-server

I would like to search files in my lan easily. (over 500k files on SMB shares, it would take ages with other ways)

I mean, i just need to do a quick search on **file names, i don't care content indexing at all**, as most of my files are in a proprietary format, and the file name is explicative enough. But, **date range filters are a must for me**.

I just need a quick search like voidtools' everything can do, but in a network way

The files are on a WHS box (lol, Videos and Music share names are not appropriate for a company, but a license for that win2003-based os is cheaper than an xp home one!)

I tried:

1. [Lansearch pro](http://www.softperfect.com/products/lspro/): it is not good for me, as i need a quick index
2. [Network Search Engine](http://www.softperfect.com/products/searchengine/): it would be perfect, but does not offer a date range filter
3. Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express, but it is horrible! First, does NOT index filenames, and then, my Core2Duo is not powerful enough to run it smoothly.
4. Google Desktop with a proxy on localhost to make it run on the lan, but i don't like the hacked result.
5. The preinstalled Windows Search 4.0 but it sucks totally in choosing the relevance of data - uninstalled
6. [Docco](http://tockit.sourceforge.net/docco/)... what's that?

I am considering to try:

1. [Ibm omnifind](http://omnifind.ibm.yahoo.net/productinfo.php)
2. [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) (can it work as a client? did not investigated yet)
3. [Strigi](http://strigi.sourceforge.net/) (it looks like that it can work as a client, right?)

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: docfetcher and strigi are not good because they dont offer date filter

Comment: ibm omnifind seems very good, but it's not ok, because seems there is no way to make it index other extensions, and does not offer date filter too...

Comment: Did you ever settle on something? I am looking for something similar. Does Solr work? that seems to be the most common suggestion. I tried elasticsearch but didn't know how to add a network path as an index to it.

Comment: No, i didn't found a solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

try [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), it also has a date filter when you configure it.

[here](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) is a php client to solr and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/) is a tutorial from developer works for setting this up.

when it does not fullfill all your needs, you can also extend it.

Comment: i forgot to reply: i don't like solr. I like something like google desktop...

Answer (score 1):

The [google search appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: it would be great, but we are too small for such a solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple Windows search utility that will search network shares as easily as the local drive and fits your description. You can download it from [here](http://www.gardeniers.com/files/Where_Install.exe). It's freeware, so comes with no warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my company.
Lot of files/directories on a Windows network share.
Biggest: ~50 million files in 25 million directories.

I wrote a little tool which does the directory enumerations in parallel.
There's a pretty nice speedup on network shares using this method.

Source code:
https://github.com/blaubart69/find_win32

- right now it's running on Windows only (.NET framework)
- command line
- simple date filter (newer/older)
- regex on filename